# Function that returns object with same keys as the input object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I attempt to write a function `fn()` with the following properties:

1. Takes a single argument `x` which is an object with optional keys "a" and "b" (for simplicity, each field may be numeric)
2. It outputs a new object with the same keys as provided in the input object but each field is a specific class (a->A, b->B), i.e. the desired behavior is:

- if I call fn({a: 1, b: 1}) I receive {a: A, b: B}
- if I call fn({b:1}) I receive {b: B} and
- if I call fn({}) I receive {}.

You can take the numeric values in the input object as initialization values for the classes in the output object. Also, new fields "c", "d", "e", ... may be added later to this function.

I struggle to set this up on the type level but also in the JS code. I have written the following code which raises Typescript errors:

- Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof OutputObject'.ts(2344)
- Type 'Partial' is not assignable to type 'Pick<OutputObject, K>'.ts(2322)

```
class A {}
class B {} 

interface InputObject {
a: number,
b: number
}

interface OutputObject {
a: A,
b: B
}

// My failed attempt at writing fn()

const fn = <
    TObj extends Partial<InputObject>,
    K extends keyof TObj
>(x: TObj): Pick<OutputObject, K> => {

    let returnValue: Partial<OutputObject> = {}

    if (x.a) {
        returnValue.a = new A()
    }

    if (x.b) {
        returnValue.b = new B()
    }

    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: • Please explicitly write out which errors you're encountering and why you either can't fix them or don't expect them. ("produces errors" isn't sufficient for a [mre]) • TS can't follow the sort of `Pick`-to-`Pick` logic you're doing here easily. I'd just use type assertions and the like to avoid the errors, perhaps as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLOGVN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you. It's almost there. What is still missing is correct handling of the empty object, const v = fn({ }) erorrs with `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<InputObject, keyof InputObject>': a, bts(2345)`

Comment: Oh, I see it defaults the wrong way. How about [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w1GYXm) then?

Comment: Works as needed. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, probably not for a number of hours since it's now my bed time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript won't be able to follow the logic inside the implementation of `fn()` to verify that it conforms to the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) relationship of [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)ing the same keys from the `OutputObject` and `InputObject` types. You'll essentially need [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to loosen the type checking enough to proceed. That means you have to be careful that your code acts as advertised, since the compiler can't really check it.

Here's a possible approach:

```
const fn = <K extends keyof InputObject = never>(
    x: Pick<InputObject, K> & Partial<InputObject>
): Pick<OutputObject, K> => {    
    let returnValue = {} as
        Pick<OutputObject, K> & Partial<OutputObject>;
    if (x.a) { returnValue.a = new A() }    
    if (x.b) { returnValue.b = new B() }    
    return returnValue;
}
```

The important pieces of this are:

- the function is only generic in `K`, the keys present in the `x` input type. This allows the compiler to more easily infer `K`, especially since we don't want any extra keys which could happen if `x` were a *subtype* of `Pick<InputObject, K>`.
- if you pass in `{}`, the compiler fails to infer `K` properly, and would normally fall back to `keyof InputObject`, which is exactly the opposite of what we want. We want [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), meaning the absence of any keys.  So there's a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `never`.
- the input type is [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `Partial<InputObject>` so the compiler is sure inside the function that if a property exists with key `a` or `b`, then it is of the `InputObject` value type. That's needed because object types in TS are not sealed. The value `{a: 1, b: "hello"}` is technically of type `Pick<InputObject, "a">`, because you could write `interface Foo extends Pick<InputObject, "a"> {b: string}` and use a `Foo`.  We want to prevent such possibilities.
- the type assertion for `returnValue` is a lie at the time it is made, since `{}` is unlikely to be of type `Pick<OutputObject, K>`. But the idea is that it will be true by the time the function returns.
- the asserted type is also intersected with `Partial<OutputObject>` for the same reason as the aformentioned intersection; this lets the compiler know that it's okay to index into `returnValue` with `a` and `b`.

Okay, let's test it:

```
const v = fn({ a: 1 });
// const v: Pick<OutputObject, "a">
const w = fn({});
// const w: Pick<OutputObject, never>
const x = fn({ b: 2 });
// const x: Pick<OutputObject, "b">
const y = fn({ a: 1, b: 2 })
// const y: Pick<OutputObject, "a" | "b">
```

Looks good. The output types are what we expect them to be.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-NRlWqNZb5E1Rusvh7DbsTWRzX6pdlA8HFRg+kZQ9hSY7I9Bsm641tPUbTcboAAfJMpoA)

Comment: Is it possible to make this without type assertion?

Comment: Assuming you're asking "can the compiler verify the type safety" then the answer is no, you have to loosen type checking via something like a type assertion, as explained in the answer above.